# show $d(f,g)=\int \min(\vert f-g \vert, 1) \ d\mu$ is a psuedo metric

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a *finite* measure space and let $f,g \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$. Show that the following 
$$d(f,g)=\int \min(\vert f-g \vert, 1) \ d\mu$$
is a pseudo metric on $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$.

---

**Thoughts:** I have shown positive and symmetry but I am struggling with the triangle inequality. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to prove that
$$\min\{|f(x)-h(x)|,1\}\leq \min\{|f(x)-g(x)|,1\}+\min\{|g(x)-h(x)|,1\}\qquad\forall\>x\in X\ .$$
Fix an $x\in X$, and let
$$f(x)-g(x)=:u,\qquad g(x)-h(x)=:v\ .$$
Then we have to prove that
$$\min\{|u+v|,1\}\leq\min\{|u|,1\}+\min\{|v|,1\}\ .$$
*Proof.* If $|u|\geq1$ then
$$\min\{|u+v|,1\}=1\leq\min\{|u|,1\}+\min\{|v|,1\}\ ,$$
and similarly, if $|v|\geq1$. If $|u|<1$ and $|v|<1$ then
$$\min\{|u+v|,1\}\leq|u+v|\leq|u|+|v|=\min\{|u|,1\}+\min\{|v|,1\}\ .$$